# How to break lines in LaTeX Bibliography

Tags: latex, line-breaks, bibliography

I have a very long url in my bibliography that it's not broken so appears outside margins. How could I fixed id? some breakline stuff?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `url` package [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/url.html), which will automatically allow linebreaks.

You mention in your comment that you are already using the package. Have a look at section 5.2, then, and allow extra linebreaks.

Comment: Well, I am using it.. :/ I use .bib files. Thanks!

Comment: Where I should add breaklines? I tried before and after begin document. Thanks :)